# Left join and possible break down by date group

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables (Table_1 and Table_2) as below

```
A1  A2      A3       A4         A5
5   MARS    200.00   Skids      3/1/2023
4   MARS    0        Each       3/1/2023
3   MARS    0        Each       3/1/2023
2   MARS    0        Each       3/1/2023
1   MARS    0        Skids      3/1/2023
5   MARS    0        Each       2/1/2023
4   MARS    0        Skids      2/1/2023
3   MARS    0        Each       2/1/2023
2   MARS    196.5    Skids      2/1/2023
1   MARS    0        Each       2/1/2023
```

and

```
B1  B2  B3
1   77  3/1/2023
2   0   3/1/2023
2   0   2/1/2023
1   76  2/1/2023
1   0   1/1/2023
2   0   1/1/2023
1   0   1/1/2023
3   0   1/1/2023
```

My goal is to use LEFT JOIN to insert row when A1 match with B1 and A5 match with B3 and if not match then NULL. I expect the result below

```
A1      A2      A3       A4      A5         B1      B2      B3
5       MARS    200.00  Skids   3/1/2023    NULL    NULL    NULL
4       MARS    0       Each    3/1/2023    NULL    NULL    NULL
3       MARS    0       Each    3/1/2023    NULL    NULL    NULL
2       MARS    0       Each    3/1/2023    2       0       3/1/2023
1       MARS    0       Skids   3/1/2023    1       77      3/1/2023
5       MARS    0       Each    2/1/2023    NULL    NULL    NULL
4       MARS    0       Skids   2/1/2023    NULL    NULL    NULL
3       MARS    0       Each    2/1/2023    NULL    NULL    NULL
2       MARS    196.50  Skids   2/1/2023    2       0       2/1/2023
1       MARS    0       Each    2/1/2023    1       76      2/1/2023
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        1       0       1/1/2023
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        3       0       1/1/2023
```

My query

```
select a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a,A5, b.B1, b,B2, b,B3
from Table_1 a
left join Table_2 B on a.A1 = b.B1
group by a.A5
```

It does not work as I expect. Look like I got duplicate and not break down by group.

Comment: you said ' A5 match with B3 ', why don;t you add that to your ON condition (with AND)? Also change your LEFT JOIN to FULL OUTER JOIN (because you want antries from both tables, regardless of they match, or not. Why do you use GROUP BY (what do you expect to gain by it, there is no aggregation)

Comment: Your results don't really make sense. You have 8 rows in table B, but only 6 results for table B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a full outer join here:

```sql
SELECT a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a,A5, b.B1, b,B2, b,B3
FROM Table_1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_2 B
    ON a.A1 = b.B1 AND a.A5 = b.B3;
```

If you happen to be using a database which does not directly support full outer join (such as MySQL), you may simulate as the union of a left and right join:

```sql
SELECT a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a,A5, b.B1, b,B2, b,B3
FROM Table_1 a
LEFT JOIN Table_2 B
    ON a.A1 = b.B1 AND a.A5 = b.B3
UNION ALL
SELECT a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a,A5, b.B1, b,B2, b,B3
FROM Table_1 a
RIGHT JOIN Table_2 B
    ON a.A1 = b.B1 AND a.A5 = b.B3
WHERE a.A1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Excellent!. Thank you. I owe you a cup of coffee.